# Radius of convergence of product of two power series

Tags: complex-analysis

let the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be $R_1$ and that of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$ be $R_2$ then what about radius of
 $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_nz^n$
if $$
\lim\sup\left\vert \frac{a_{n+1}b_{n+1}}{a_{n}b_{n}}\right\vert =\lim
\sup\left\vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right\vert \lim\sup\left\vert
\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}\right\vert,
$$
then why is $R_1R_2\leq R$.

The same thing happens to sum and division, WHY?

Comment: what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} z^n$ ? and more generally of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{-n} z^n$ ? and of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{-n} z^n n^4$ ? hence if $|a_n| < C R^n$ then... and conversely if the radius of convergence is $R$, then ...

Comment: So... you think the product of $\sum a_n z^n$ and $\sum b_n z^n$ is $\sum a_n b_n z^n$? Is that how they multiply sums in your class/book?

Comment: I hope you understood what i meant. I want an answer sir.How we multiply sums  will not change the answer?

Comment: where did i say the product is like that but in comman terminology it is called product of series.

Comment: It is probabily a good reason for you to justify your downvote.

Comment: The sum you have written is not the product of two power series.

Comment: Sir I admit that I have commited a mistake by using wrong term in the tittle.But i think i think i have conveyed the sense.

Comment: This is sometimes called "Hadamard product" of the two power series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\limsup(x_ny_n)\le\limsup(x_n)\limsup(y_n)$, and strict inequality is possible. For instance, $x_n=1$ if $n$ is even, $x_n=0$ if $n$ is odd, $y_n=x_{n+1}$.